# Find all hidden ".idea" folders in system

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

I am using PHPStorm 8 for programming. PHPStorm automatically creates a hidden folder called ".idea", where all project-specifiy settings are stored.

How am I able to find all these ".idea" folders in the entire system?

(I like to find and remove all of these folder)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from **Terminal.app**. Navigate to the topmost directory with:

```
cd /
```

Then type this command:

```
find . -name ".idea" -exec rm -r {} \;
```

This will remove all `.idea` directories which are owned by You (more specificaly You have the rights to delete them). If You want to delete all of them, add `sudo` in front of this command.

NOTE: calling `sudo` without knowing what You are doing can be dangerous.